# syntax error when using substring in a join expression with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.5, python-db-api

I'm working with postgresql using the Python DB API.

The substring expression I'm using works fine when on its own, but when I put it in the context of a join command I get a syntax error, and I can't find a solution to this in any tutorial or other question.

The expression I'm using is

```
    select substring(path, 10, 28) 'my_substr' from log limit 3")
```

and it gives the result

```
    [('',), ('candidate-is-jerk',), ('goats-eat-googles',)]
```

which is what I want. (It trims off /articles/ in this path.)

The context I want to place it in is a join expression, like this:

```
    select articles.author, articles.slug
    from articles 
    join log on articles.slug = substring(path, 10, 28) 'my_substr'
    from log
```

If I didn't need a substring, the expression would be

```
    join log on articles.slug = log.path,
```

but as it is, the 'path' won't match 'slug', but with the substring in place it does.

I've tried using brackets, using "as" before 'my_substr', but all give the same syntax error.

How can I create this expression with the proper syntax?

Comment: Is `'my_substr'` an alias for the column? If so, then you don't need it in an update. Just remove it.

Comment: `select articles.author, articles.slug
    from articles 
    join log on articles.slug = substring(log.path, 10, 28)`

Comment: The string constant `my_substr` is completely wrong there. If that is supposed to be an alias: if at all you need to use double quotes for identifiers. Single quotes are only for string constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot and don't need to alias column expression in expressions other than a list of columns for a `SELECT`.

You also have a stray `FROM` in there.

Try:

```
SELECT articles.author,
       articles.slug
       FROM articles 
            INNER JOIN log
                       ON articles.slug = substring(log.path, 10, 28);
```

And finally, if you use aliases, don't enclose them in single quotes (`'`), these are for string literals in SQL. If you need to have special characters in the alias use double quotes (`"`), otherwise no quotes (and nothing else) at all.